# Copying file names from upload to textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that will copy the file names and add them to the textarea. Everything works but when you add more files, the first ones are deleted. How to fix it?

```js
updateList = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('file');
  
  var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
  
  output.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
    output.innerHTML += '\n' + input.files.item(i).name + '';
  }
  output.innerHTML += ' \n';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Display file name in page after selecting file in file input</title>
</head>

<form>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple 
       onchange="javascript:updateList()" />
<br/>Selected files:
<textarea id="fileList"></textarea>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

FIDDLE:    https://jsfiddle.net/yhw8zfue/

Comment: you should not be using innerHTML for a textarea

Comment: Why would the first ones be deleted if you loop over all the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting your textarea value to empty string.

You can fix by removing the line:

`output.innerHTML = '';`

Answer (score 1):

When you add more files the function will run again and updste your filelist. but in your code you reset the list of files here:

```
output.innerHTML = '';
```

so instead you want to have whats currently in there. replace it with that:

```
updateList = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('file');
  var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
  output.innerHTML = output.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
    output.innerHTML += '\n' + input.files.item(i).name + '';
  }
  output.innerHTML += ' \n';
  }
```